# When I click on a treelist, I want a word to appear in a textbox with devExpress

Tags: c#, visual-studio, events, text, devexpress

When I click on a word in my treelist, I want another word to appear in my textbox. I know I need the click event method, but am not sure how to implement that. I am using DevExpress and Visual Studios.

In my treelist, for example I have the options: "print" and "highlight". If I select the "print" option, I want the word "hello" to appear in the textbox.

Comment: Can you please give me an example? This is what I have now. Textbox1.Text("Hello"); My textbox1 is in another file, so I am getting the error that I am missing a reference. How do I reference the other file?

Comment: Honestly, I am not sure. I believe I am, but I am using a filter in c# Visual Studio web application.

Comment: I believe that's how I do it too. My Textbox1 is in another .cs file. How do I access it? Thank yous o much.

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at the [TreeList.FocusedNodeChanged Event](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraTreeListTreeList_FocusedNodeChangedtopic):

First you have to Hook up to an event to your TreeList. You can do this via the Designer or manually like:

```
treeList1.FocusedNodeChanged += new DevExpress.XtraTreeList.FocusedNodeChangedEventHandler(this.treeList1_FocusedNodeChanged);
```

Create the corresponding method, which will be triggered every time the focused node in your TreeList got changed:

```
private void treeList1_FocusedNodeChanged(object sender, DevExpress.XtraTreeList.FocusedNodeChangedEventArgs e)
{
        textBox1.Text = e.Node.GetDisplayText(treeListColumn1); //set you text here
}
```